# Why negate z when constructing projection matrix OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++, linear-algebra

I constructed an orthographic projection matrix from  [this](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/orthographic-projection-matrix) article on scratchpixel.com:

```
Matrix4 ortho(float l, float r, float b, float t, float n, float f) {
   return Matrix4(
       2/(r-l), 0, 0, -(r+l)/(r-l), //row 0
       0, 2/(t-b), 0, -(t+b)/(t-b), //row 1
       0, 0, -2/(f-n), -(f+n)/(f-n), //row 2
       0, 0, 0, 1 //row 3
   );
}
```

, where `r, l, t, b, n, f` are right, left, top, bottom, near and far corners of the view box.

Now I tested out this matrix using the default parameters of the view box `ortho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1)` to see if I get an identity matrix. However I'm getting:

```
 1, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 1, 0, 0,
 0, 0, -1, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 1
```

Basically this will result in z coordinate of every transformed point to be negated.

Is it standard to negate the z coordinate when constructing projection matrix? What could be the purpose behind that?

Comment: In my opinion flipping $Z$ is both confusing and unnecessary. It changes the handedness of the different spaces. It's just an arbitrary decision that was made for OpenGL afaik.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your scene is constructed based on right-handed coordinates.

If you are using OpenGL, yes. If you are using Direct3D, no.

The projection matrix maps [-n, -f] into [0, 1]. This weird property comes from the fact that the eye coordinates are right-handed, but the clip space (NDC) uses left-handed coordinates. Hence the implementation of `ortho()`.

Direct3D uses a z-axis that goes outwards the screen. Implementations for Direct3D projection matrices will not produce negated z when coupled with your application.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify did you mean to write `In OpenGL screen-space (Normalized device coordinate), larger z value means FARTHER points.`? I mean if OpenGL uses z-axis that goes inwards the screen.

Comment: [From this link:](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) "Note that the eye coordinates are defined in the right-handed coordinate system, but NDC uses the left-handed coordinate system. That is, the camera at the origin is looking along -Z axis in eye space, but it is looking along +Z axis in NDC." --- So larger values mean farther away in NDC

Comment: So this is not correct: "In OpenGL screen-space (Normalized device coordinate), larger z value means closer points."

Comment: I see. I was wrong indeed. The misunderstanding came from my thought that the projection matrix maps [n, f] to [0, 1]. What actually happens is the matrix maps [-n, -f] to [0, 1]. I'll edit the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the purpose behind that?

Have a look at the first lines and the first image in the Perspective Projection section of [this link](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html). For the answer to your question, it is not important that you used an orthographic projection, even though there is also a corresponding section in the link.

The issue is how OpenGL defines its coordinate systems. Quote from the link:

> Note that the eye coordinates are defined in the right-handed coordinate system, but NDC uses the left-handed coordinate system. That is, the camera at the origin is looking along -Z axis in eye space, but it is looking along +Z axis in NDC.

So if you transform between them, you need to swap the z-axis. This is the whole purpose behind it, switching the handedness of the coordinate systems.

> Is it standard to negate the z coordinate when constructing projection matrix?

Depends on your API and how the coordinate systems are defined. In OpenGL, you need to do this.